# Python "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" in django code

Tags: python

I am trying to create an app that will enable a user to upload a file. I want to create a model that will handle the file upload.

```
from django import forms

class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    file  = forms.FileField()
```

But upon doing this when I syncdb I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 219, in execute
    self.validate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 249, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 36, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 146, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 61, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 78, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/roy/projects/qsourcing/qsl/models.py", line 5
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)                                        file  = forms.FileField()   
                                                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What does the title have to do with the problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO roykasa, good formatting is your friend..

Answer (score 3):

Start reading your backtrace from the bottom:

```
  File "/home/roy/projects/qsourcing/qsl/models.py", line 5
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=50)                                        file  = forms.FileField()   
                                                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

In this case there is a problem in **line 5** of **models.py**.  You are missing a new line

Answer (score 0):

Soner is correct.  This issues is most likely caused by incorrect formatting.  I have come across this error a few times after I copied code from a tutorial or blog and then pasted it directly into my project.  If you see this error after copy and pasting code from a tutorial or blog, simply delete the pasted code and manually type out the code instead.

Best,